# Printing random 2-dimensional array though a user-defined function in C

Tags: c, arrays, output, user-defined-functions

I have to print out the results of an array in a 25x2 table, but the tricky part is that the array has to be in main, while a user defined function has to output the array. Im not sure how to start this, let alone get the desired output:

```
    Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015: 
    Time of Day     Temperature in degrees F 
    0               85
    1               80
    2               97
    3               90
    4               73
    ........
    Midnight        68
```

Here is the code I have so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int get_value (void) 
    {
       return rand()%41+60; 
    }

    int calc_results (int a[], int n)
    {
        int i, j, maximum, minimum, average,sum;

    printf ("Temperature conditions on October 17th, 2015:\n");


        int a[25][2]; //not sure what to do here
        for(i = 0; i<25;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                printf ("%d\n"), a[i][j];
            }


        maximum = a[0]; 
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
            if(maximum < a[i])
                maximum = a[i];
            }
        printf("Maximum Temperature for the day: %d\n", maximum);


        minimum = a[0]; 
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
            if(minimum > a[i])
                minimum = a[i];
            }
        printf("Minimum Temperature for the day: %d\n", minimum);


        float avg; 
        sum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            sum+=a[i];

        avg=(float)sum/25;
        printf("Average Temperature for the day: %f\n", avg);


        return 0;
    }


    int main ()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        int average,i;

        //printf("These are the temperatures for the day\n");
        int temp[25];
            for (i=0;i<25;i++) 
            {
            temp[i]= get_value(); 
            printf("%d\n",temp[i]); //this prints out the temp results correctly but as a one dimensional array
            }

    calc_results(temp,i); 

    return 0;
    }
```

Also all those loops have to be done in calc_results, I can't make another user defined function or move any of them into main. And any help is appreciated! At this point I just want to get it into a table, I don't mind if the output isn't 100% the same.

I'm also new at programming and this is my first time doing something like this so I'm really sorry if I'm just overlooking some obvious error or completely butchering my code.

Comment: You don't need 2-d array . Use the array which you pass to function why re-declaration .And also in you function `calc_results` there is a typo in `printf` in `for loop` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static const int MIN_TEMP = 60;
static const int MAX_TEMP = 101;

int get_value (void) 
{
    return rand()%(MAX_TEMP-MIN_TEMP)+MIN_TEMP; 
}

int calc_results (int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j, maximum = MIN_TEMP, minimum = MAX_TEMP, average,sum;
    float avg; 

    printf ("Temperature conditions on October 17th, 2015:\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
        if(a[i] > maximum)
            maximum = a[i];
        if(a[i] < minimum)
            minimum = a[i];

        sum+=a[i];
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("Maximum Temperature for the day: %d\n", maximum);
    printf("Minimum Temperature for the day: %d\n", minimum);

    avg=(float)sum/n;
    printf("Average Temperature for the day: %f\n", avg);

    return 0;
}


int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int average,i;

    //printf("These are the temperatures for the day\n");
    int temp[25];
    for (i=0;i<25;i++) 
    {
        temp[i]= get_value(); 
        //printf("%d\n",temp[i]); //this prints out the temp results correctly but as a one dimensional array
    }

    calc_results(temp,i); 

    return 0;
}
```

Please note:

- You don't need to create a new array in `calc_results`, it's enough with the one being passed to `calc_results`. Given that you pass the array's size as `n` that will be enough to iterate as well as calculate the average, maximum and minimum values.
- You can print both the index value and the temperature value for that index in the same line by using a proper format string such as `"%d\t%d\n"`
- You can do everything in the same iteration (keep `maximum`, `minimum` and `sum`)
- For functions like `get_value` I usually find it clearer to set max and min values such as `MAX_TEMP` and `MIN_TEMP` and just use those.
- You have to initialize `maximum` and `minimum` to at least your limits. The usual way to do this is to use constants like `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

I guess it's fairly trivial to add the 'Midnight' text where needed, as well as formatting for the title lines.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem new C programmers run into, is picking up the keyboard and starting to code before they have throught through the logic of their code. This is normal, but very inefficient. Take time to think through your requirements, what values are needed, when, and where they will come from.

The first issue is the array, you will declare and fill the array in `main()` and then pass the array to `calc_results`. Your `get_value` is fine. The first question is what value will `calc_results` return? If no value, then make it `void` unless you need to return a success/failure status (your output does that here).

How do you pass the filled array to `calc_results`? When an array is passed as a function argument, the first dimension of the array will *decay to a pointer*. Meaning that `a[25]` will decay to `*a` when passed as a parameter. This tells you that a proper declaration for `calc_results` can look like:

```
void calc_results (int *a, int n)
```

Then what is `calc_results` to do? Looking at your question, it will: (1) print a heading for the daily temps (2) output all 25 values `0` (first midnight) through the following `Midnight`. The only caveat there is the second occurrence of midnight should be output as `Midnight` instead of `24`. You will next find the max/min temps, `sum` all temps, and finally divide by `25` to get the average.

How many loops? To answer that question, you first ask, what has to take place in the loop anyway? Well, everything you need to access an individual temperature for will need to be handled in the loop. That will be (1) the printing of the values; (2) finding the max/min temps and (3) summing the temps. Is there any reason all this cannot be done in the same loop? (think)

What about the average? Does that need to be in the loop? No, but it does need `sum` which will be a result of the loop, so `average` must be handled after the loop completes.

What about printing all the max/min/avg output, is there any reason that shouldn't take place all at once after the needed values are known?

After you have answered all the questions, now it is time to pick up the keyboard. Working though your mental outline, you can arrive as something that is similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for rand ()          */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN/INT_MAX  */
#include <time.h>   /* for srand ()         */

int get_value (void)
{
    return rand () % 41 + 60;
}

void calc_results (int *a, int n)
{
    /* declare & initialize needed variables */
    int i, maximum, minimum, average, sum;
    float avg = 0.0;

    i = average = sum = 0;
    maximum = INT_MIN;
    minimum = INT_MAX;

    /* print header */
    printf ("Temperature conditions on October 17th, 2015:\n"
            "Time of Day     Temperature in degrees F\n");

    /* only one loop is needed */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        /* print hourly data */
        if (i < 24)
            printf ("%-16d%d\n", i, a[i]);
        else
            printf ("%-16s%d\n", "Midnight", a[i]);

        /* find max/min, compute sum */
        if (a[i] > maximum)
            maximum = a[i];

        if (a[i] < minimum)
            minimum = a[i];

        sum += a[i];
    }

    /* compute average */
    avg = (float) sum / 25;

    /* print remaining statistics */
    printf ("Maximum Temperature for the day: %d\n", maximum);
    printf ("Minimum Temperature for the day: %d\n", minimum);
    printf ("Average Temperature for the day: %f\n", avg);
}

int main (void)
{
    /* declare & initialize needed variables */
    int i = 0;
    int temp[25] = {0};

    srand (time (NULL));  /* set random seed */

    /* fill array */
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        temp[i] = get_value ();

    /* calcumate stats, ouput data */
    calc_results (temp, i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_temp
Temperature conditions on October 17th, 2015:
Time of Day     Temperature in degrees F
0               81
1               85
2               98
3               67
4               82
5               65
6               96
7               98
8               62
9               77
10              88
11              63
12              96
13              81
14              74
15              73
16              62
17              79
18              85
19              96
20              68
21              90
22              86
23              94
Midnight        96
Maximum Temperature for the day: 98
Minimum Temperature for the day: 62
Average Temperature for the day: 81.680000
```